# How can I convert some png files to a video using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

The file appears and when I open it it just closes. I'm on Linux Mint Cinnamon.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob


size = (500,500)
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('home/user/Desktop/Images/*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)


out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
cvWaitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo error: `cvWaitKey(0)` to `cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: Yes, but `cv2.waitKey(0)` is not needed in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fundamentally correct, but openCV video writing seems to be very sensitive to the machine environment, codecs etc.
As an alternative, you might consider the imageio library, for example:

```
import imageio

writer = imageio.get_writer('movie.mp4')

for img in img_array:
    writer.append_data(img)
writer.close()
```

The examples are [here.](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#iterate-over-frames-in-a-movie)